# How would one express units like "KB/s" in words?

Tags: expressions

I'd like to write a comment for the code lines which convert the units, for example "KB/s" to "B/s".

Is the following an appropriate expression?

"convert everything into byte and second units"

Comment: Hi Hanul, firstly, **proofreading** is not encouraged in this site. Therefore I'm not posting this as an answer.  Why don't you try : '**Convert everything into Bytes per second**'. Also, when you comment a code, you should keep it short and simple. Try: '**Convert to Bytes/sec**'.

Comment: @VarunKN, I think there's an interesting and ontopic question implicit here.  I've changed the title to refocus the question.

Comment: @Varun KN I didn't realize that proofreading is not encouraged in this site. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @Codeswitcher, but don't you think that takes the focus off the OP's original question ?

Comment: @VarunKN Sorry for the late response but your comment is the answer what I just wanted. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

To convert "Kilo Bytes per second" to "Bytes per second"